# Adding new installer class in windows application getting compiler error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I have created a widows application with setup project. I compiled and build.Everything looks fine.

For changing the configuration file during installation am trying to add a new Installer file. when i add it by default i get the below code

```
Collapse | Copy Code

[RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class Installer : Installer
    {
        public Installer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

When i compile this Am gettin
**Circular base class dependency involving 'windows_setup.Installer' and 'windows_setup.Installer'**

windows setup is the name space i used for the application. Then i found that i need to create the new classs which inbherits Installer.So i changed my class name to

```
public partial class MyInstaller : Installer
```

Now am Getting

**Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'windows_setup.Installer' is less accessible than class 'windows_setup.MyInstaller'**

Suggest your ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't have a public class inheriting from an internal class for example. Try to set everything as internal if not required outside, or public otherwise.

Comment: i Changed to Myinstaller. as mentioned Now am getting "consistent accessibility: base class 'windows_setup.Installer' is less accessible than class 'windows_setup.MyInstaller"

Comment: What is Installer definition ? public, internal ? private ? if it is internal, MyInstaller has to be internal as well!

Comment: namespace windows_setup
{
    partial class Installer
    {     No definition given...what is the default one ?

Comment: private. You should change it to public partial class Installer

Comment: Thanks for your help.The issue got resolved no compilation Error. But My Installer Class is not getting called ? Am i missing something

Comment: Are you overriding the Install method in your installer class?

Comment: Yes. Thanks Kreep. Added "System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();"  and Debugging works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Either change class `Installer` and `MyInstaller` to public.

Write Something like this:

`System.Configuration.Install.Installer` and class definition should be `public partial`

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public partial class MyInstaller : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
{
    public MyInstaller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: 'windows_setup.Installer.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override

Comment: Another problem which has nothing to do with current question. You are trying to override a method which is not marked as virtual in parent class or does not exist at all...